# Accessing a JPanel inside another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have multiple panels nested inside other panels and I'd like to get a *JPanel* from there.

I've tried:

```
Component[] components = this.getComponents();
```

for both JFrame and a JPanel but it returns me only `javax.swing.JRootPane` and not any `JPanels`.

Is there another function I am not aware of that would return all *JPanels* inside JFrame or JPanel?

Comment: *"I have multiple panels nested inside other panels and I'd like to get a JPanel from there."*  This reeks of `extends JPanel` which would be half the problem..

Comment: Is there a problem with extends JPanel that I don't know of? I'd like to use multiple panels for my game because they are easy to handle. Thanks :)

Comment: *"I'd like to use multiple panels.."*  I've used thousands of panels without extending them.  The only time it makes much sense to extend a panel is when doing custom painting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing the JFrame's JRootPane, a component that holds a JLayeredPane, a component which holds the contentPane, a component which holds your JPanels:

[image]
* [Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

I suggest that you not do what you're trying to do since your method of getting references is very brittle and will break if you change the structure of your GUI. Instead use fields to hold the key references that you need access to, be they JPanel fields or collection fields such as an ArrayList, or a field that references objects of your own classes.